# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol') / (Botman Laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel, widget, botman

I want to embed my botman chatbot into a modal. (using laravel/php)
When I use the first script, it opens a widget that looks and replies perfectly. But I want to embed my chatbot into something like a modal. The second script looks perfect and can be embedded, but the chatbot doesn't reply to this method.

This is the only difference between the two scripts

```
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
```

Widget

[image]

```
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/chat.js'></script>
```

chat
[image]

I tried to make my chatbot the entire screen instead of a small block in the corner. I tried using the chat part instead of the widget part, but then the bot didn't reply at all.

I already tried using the frameEndpoint: '/iFrameUrl'` in different ways, but there was no result.

WIDGET VIEW

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var botmanWidget = {
            title: 'ChatBot',
            introMessage: "Type 'start' to begin the quiz",
            placeholderText: 'Ask Me Something',
            mainColor: '#F28240',
            bubbleBackground: '#F28240',
            aboutText: '',
            aboutLink: 'www.bookworkflow.com',
            bubbleAvatarUrl: '',
            desktopWidth: 1000,
            desktopHeight: 800,
        };

    </script>
     <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CHAT VIEW

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var botmanWidget = {
            title: 'ChatBot',
            introMessage: "Type 'start' to begin the quiz",
            placeholderText: 'Ask Me Something',
            mainColor: '#F28240',
            bubbleBackground: '#F28240',
            aboutText: '',
            aboutLink: 'www.bookworkflow.com',
            bubbleAvatarUrl: '',
            desktopWidth: 500,
            desktopHeight: 800,
        };

    </script>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/chat.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the console log:

```
chat.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')
    at chat.js:1:19413
    at chat.js:1:13244
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t.exports (chat.js:1:12134)
    at t.exports (chat.js:1:21377)
(anonymous) @ chat.js:1
(anonymous) @ chat.js:1
t.exports @ chat.js:1
t.exports @ chat.js:1
Promise.then (async)
callAPI @ chat.js:1
e.say @ chat.js:1
r.handleKeyPress @ chat.js:1
m @ chat.js:1
```

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: As you're new (welcome!) I'd also stronly advise you to take the [tour] so you understand how the site works.

Comment: Such external widgets can often be "picky" about the environment they get initialized in. And with a modal usually being hidden at page load via `display: none`, depending on the widget and how exactly it works, that can sometimes break things. Check the browser console for errors first of all. See if the provider of that widget has any additional information on how it needs to be initialized, and whether something needs to be done different, when you want to use it in a modal.

Comment: Hi @ADyson , I corrected all mistakes and I also added the console log message. Thanks for the nice welcome message.

Comment: Hi @CBroe , thanks I also added the console log , looks like something todo with my JS

Comment: _"looks like something todo with my JS"_ - the error appears to be coming from the chatbot script itself though. You could try and only insert that external script when the modal gets shown for the first time (_after_ it has been made visible), and see if that changes anything.